# add screenshot to email without being saved to library

Tags: ios, screenshot

I need to be able to send an email inside my app with a screenshot of the current display of the iphone, attached to it. You click a button and i takes you into an email with the screenshot attached and without the picture being saved to the camera. The button you press should be in an actionsheet. I know the code to send an email and the action sheet, but i need to know how to make the button to the mail be in the actionsheet including the screenshot.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Place your current code or requirement image for a better idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIActionSheet *options = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Options" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Email", nil];
[options showInView:self.view];

#pragma mark ActionSheet Delegate
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    switch (buttonIndex)
    {
        case 0:
        {

        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}

#pragma mark Email

//Allocating Memory for MailComposer
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];    

    mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSData *exportData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image ,1.0);
    [mailController addAttachmentData:exportData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"Screenshot.jpeg"];
    [self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
```

EDIT:

```
#pragma mark MailComposer Delegate
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Remember to add the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate in the header file.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thnaks! However when I've written this code i get the error "Use of undeclared identifier 'selfwindow', and the error "Property 'window' not found on object of type ViewController*. I'm a beginner in coding so I appreciate your help. Can you have both "MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate" and a another one in the header file?

Comment: change the self.window to self.view.

Comment: still have the first error and instead I got "Reciever type 'CALayer' for instance message is a forward declaration"

Comment: change the other window word to view as well.

Comment: the first error is gone, but the sceond error "Reciever type 'CALayer' for instance message is a forward declaration" is still there

Comment: please #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> at the top of your code

Comment: Great! Thanks it works! Do you need something like a UIAlertView or something to let the person know if the mail failed to send?

Comment: can i add that anywhere under implementation in the ViewController.m?